# Предлагается создать новый вопрос при закрытии дубликатом

Tags: предложение, статус-так-задумано, дубликаты

Заметил такую штуку. В настоящий момент когда вопрос закрывается дубликатом, то появляется следующая надпись

> Подобный вопрос задавали ранее и на него уже получен ответ. Если представленные ответы не являются исчерпывающими, пожалуйста, **задайте новый вопрос**.

Дак вот, допустим человек поискал, нашел нужный вопрос, но *"ответы не являются исчерпывающими"* и он создает новый. Его тут же закрывают дубликатом, где и предлагается создать уже третий  вопрос.

То есть фактически сообщение у дубликате предлагает создать еще один дубль вопроса, что несколько нелогично. Нужно предлагать отредактировать и переоткрыть текущий, а не создавать новый.

Comment: не совсем, подразумевается, что в новом вопросе будет указано _почему_ ответы не подходят

Comment: @Grundy дак смысл для этого создавать третий вопрос? можно отредактировать и в этом указать, почему не подходит.

Comment: можно и так :-) возможно стоит посмотреть английскую строку. Посмотрел - там точно такая же строка :-)

Comment: [Duplicate explanation should encourage improvement of original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166525/282647)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Именно так все и происходит**

Автор вопроса видит именно то сообщение, о котором вы говорите, поскольку мы и хотим, чтобы они именно *редактировали* вопрос:  [image]

Другие же пользователи видят только ссылку *"Задайте новый вопрос"* (без ссылки *Править*), поскольку в основном они попадают на страницу из поисковых систем.
И даже если у них достаточно репутации для редактирования вопроса, обычно у них несколько "иная проблема" или ее контекст. Поэтому они вряд ли смогут прояснить или уточнить, что именно имел в виду автор вопроса-дубликата.

<sub>вольный перевод ответа [@Jaydles♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167270/282647)</sub>

Comment: гугло-перевод что ли? :D

Comment: @teran, не :-) но последний абзац жесть какая-то, если поправишь будет здорово :-)

Comment: да в целом и так понятно, что автору вопроса показывается другое сообщение (не знал об этом). мотивация почему остальным именно так - не шибко то важна.

Comment: @teran, ок :-).